# Why is my python function not working properly when I call it recursively?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I'm doing a question from a previous Waterloo ccc competition (https://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/computing/2020/ccc/juniorEF.pdf problem J5)
and my code isn't working the way I expected

Here's the sample input I'm using:

3

4

3 10 8 14

1 11 12 12

6 2 3 9

Here's my code so far

```
y_size = int(input())
x_size = int(input())
mat = []

"ok".split()
for i in range(y_size):
    row = input().split()
    mat.append(row)

pos_list = [[0, 0]]
current_num = int(mat[0][0])
a = 0


def canEscape():
    global a
    global mat
    global pos_list
    global current_num
    end = y_size * x_size
    if y_size -1 * x_size -1 == current_num:
        return True
    for i in range(y_size):
        print("______")
        for j in range(x_size):
            v = (i + 1) * (j + 1)
            print(v)
            print(current_num)
            if v == current_num:
                print("ok")
                if v == end:
                    print("ok")
                a += 1
                current_num = mat[i][j]
                pos_list.append([i, j])
                canEscape()
                pos_list.pop(-1)
                a -= 1
                current_num = mat[pos_list[a][0]][pos_list[a][1]]


canEscape()
```

The problem I'm having is that I expect `if v == current_num:` to be true when I call it again. Both `current_num` and `v` are equal to 8 but the code seems to carry on with the for-in loop and break, without entering the if statement. I've made the output print `v` followed by `current_num` for every iteration of the for loop to try and figure out the problem but it seems that both variables == 8 so I really don't know what I did wrong. Did I make a silly mistake or did I structure my whole program wrong?

Comment: While I think you should restructure your solution in a way which eliminates the need for global variables.  I think the issue you maybe having in this example is that the variables x_size and y_size should also be declared as globals. You could just as easily move the declarations of these variables inside your function and eliminate all globals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having trouble following what your program is doing at all. This problem involves integer factoring, and I do not see where you're factoring integers. You definitely are not understanding that aspect of the problem.

When you calculate what cells you can go to you look at the value of your current cell. Lets say it is 6. 6 has the factors 1, 2, 3, and 6 because all of those numbers can be multiplied by another number to equal 6. So, you can go to the cells (1, 6), (6, 1), (2, 3), and (3, 2), because those are the pairs of numbers that can be multiplied together to equal 6.

Also, you never convert the lines of input into integers. When you append to the matrix, you are appending a list of strings that happen to be numbers. You must convert those into integers.

Anyways, this program will solve the problem. I copy and pasted the factoring algorithm from other threads:

```
n_rows = int(input())
n_cols = int(input())
mat = []

for i in range(n_rows):
    mat.append(list(map(lambda x: int(x), input().split()))) # Convert input strings to integers.

def reduce(f, l):
    # This is just needed for the factoring function
    # It's not relevant to the problem
    r = None
    for e in l:
        if r is None:
            r = e
        else:
            r = f(r, e)
    return r
    

def factors(n):
    # An efficient function for calculating factors.
    return set(reduce(list.__add__, 
                ([i, n//i] for i in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0)))

def get_pairs(items):
    for i in range(len(items) // 2):
        yield (items[i],items[len(items) - 1 - i]) # use yield to save memory
    if(len(items) % 2 != 0): # This is for square numbers.
        n = items[len(items) // 2]
        yield (n,n)

checked_numbers = set()

def isPath(r=1, c=1):
    # check if the testing row or column is to large.
    if r > n_rows or c > n_cols:
        return False
    y = r - 1
    x = c - 1
    n = mat[y][x]
    # If we've already checked a number with a certain value we dont need to check it again.
    if n in checked_numbers:
        return False
    checked_numbers.add(n)
    # Check if we've reached the exit.
    if(r == n_rows and c == n_cols):
        return True

    # Calculate the factors of the number, and then find all valid pairs with those factors.
    pairs = get_pairs(sorted(list(factors(n))))
    # Remember to check each pair with both combinations of every pair of factors.
    # If any of the pairs lead to the exit then we return true.
    return any([isPath(pair[0], pair[1]) or isPath(pair[1], pair[0]) for pair in pairs])

if isPath():
    print("yes");
else:
    print("no");
```

This works and it is fast. However, it if you are limited on memory and/or have a large data input size your program could easily run out of memory. I think it is likely that this will happen with some of the testing inputs but I'm not sure.. It is surely possible to write this program in a way that would use a fraction of the memory, perhaps by converting the factors function to a function that uses iterators, as well as converting the get_pairs function to somehow iterate as well.

I would imagine that this solution solves most of the testing inputs they have but will not solve the ones towards the end, because they will be very large and it will run out of memory.